# How do I use 'texir' and 'dmr' parameters?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a multinomial inverse regression as described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2098). The R package is called `textir`. It works just fine, but I am unable to map the parameters in the R package (called "nlambda" and "gamma") to (what I understand) are hyper parameters of the model as described in the paper (shape and scale parameters r and s of the gamma-hyperprior for each lambda).

```
install.packages("textir")
library("textir")
data(we8there)
cl <- NULL
fits <- dmr(cl, we8thereRatings[,'Overall',drop=FALSE],
        we8thereCounts, bins=5, gamma=1, nlambda=100)
```

Using this as a starting point, I would like to replicate Appendix 3 "A.3 Out-of-Sample Prediction Study Details", third panel ("Restaurant  Rating") on page 31 of the paper, where the authors varies the shape parameter "s". I fail to see how this implemented in the R package.

Interestingly, in another [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00401706.2013.778791) by Matt Taddy, he uses

```
fit <- mnlm(cl=NULL,counts=X, covars=V, bins=3,verb=TRUE, penalty=c(4,1))
```

and passes `penalty` parameter to supply two numbers (`mnlm()` is just another way to call `dmr()`, according to `textir` documentation). I am not able to find the documentation of this parameter, in any of the associated packages `textir`, `dmr` and `gamlr`. Also, if you drop them, or change them to absurd values (even to strings like "bla"), the output is virtually unchanged.

Comment: There was no numbering of the tables in the pdf version downloaded from that link. (Figures were numbered but not the tables)

Comment: thanks! edited the question. I was referring to Table A3 "A.3 Out-of-Sample Prediction Study Details", third panel ("Restaurant  Ratings")

Comment: What part of "no numbering ... in the pdf" did you not understand? (And they also lacked titles. The is a single instance of the two adjacent words: "Restaurant ratings" and it's not associated with any tabular display.)

Comment: @42-, you are quite right. the vertical formatting of page 31 seems to make searches in the PDF infeasible. If you scroll to page 31, there is a table at the very bottom, which I am interested in. The "A3" seems to refer to appendix 3.

Comment: If you had spelled the title correctly, a search does find it.

Comment: edited the question, thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: I'm afraid that I now understand the question but think it is too broad for SO. You are asking us to duplicate a set of results using six different methods: (MNIR & POLR; MNIR & Linear; LDA & POLR; Supervised LDA; Lasso; PLS). Surely this is a request you should have instead addressed to the paper's authors.

Comment: @42-, I am not asking SO to replicate it. I am trying to replicate it myself and to this end try to understand the parameter "s" for the MNIR subset of results of the table. The data & code (presumably) used by the author are posted above. I am just failing to understand how the parameter "s" in the paper is related to the implementation in the `dmr` and `mnlm` commands used in the tutorials ans was hoping someone might have worked with the packages before and run into similar problems.

Comment: I think this is a mixture of a theory and coding but also think that the person most likely to know the answer is the author of the papers and the package. So my advice stands: send him an email.

Comment: I agree with your accessment. I was hoping someone worked with those packages before and was able to help. Anyone who worked with them should stumble across the issue rather sooner than later, which is why I posted on SO. But yes, I  the author will surely be able to help and I will contact him. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually missed the important part of the READ me:

"Versions 2+ make [..] differ from [...] original MNIR: **penalties are chosen from full regularization paths (instead of being fixed)**...". In case anyone else runs in the same problem, one can download version 1.8.8 from github and manually install. It will them work just fine.